# ARKit/RealityKit – People Occlusion config not working

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

For some reason I can't get people occlusion to work, even though I looked at someone's question on Stackoverflow. Here is my code:

```
//Load ARView
let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

//Load people occlusion
let session = ARSession()

if let configuration = session.configuration as? ARWorldTrackingConfiguration {
    configuration.frameSemantics.insert(.personSegmentationWithDepth)
    session.run(configuration)
}

//Load custom model(not in use)
let model = try! Entity.loadModel(named: "Mug")

//Load Anchor + Entity
let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
let box = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.1)
let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: true)
let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: box, materials: [material])
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
anchor.addChild(entity)
return arView
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    self.switchOcclusion()
}
    
fileprivate func switchOcclusion() {
        
    guard let config = arView.session.configuration as ARWorldTrackingConfiguration
    else { return }
        
    guard ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsFrameSemantics(.personSegmentationWithDepth)
    else { return }
        
    switch config.frameSemantics {            
        case [.personSegmentationWithDepth]: config.frameSemantics.remove(.personSegmentationWithDepth)                    
        default: config.frameSemantics.insert(.personSegmentationWithDepth)
    }           
    arView.session.run(config)
}
```

Or there's also a cool solution with `type(of:)` method:

```
let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
config.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
arView.session.run(config)

if type(of: config).supportsFrameSemantics(.sceneDepth) {
    config.frameSemantics = .personSegmentationWithDepth
} else {
    print("This device doesn't support segmentation with depth")
}
```

Comment: For some reason I tried to do exactly what you answered and I get "Value of type 'ARViewContainer' has no member 'arView'" even when I change for Generic iOS Device

Comment: I have this exact code (except `print` has to be `fatalError` in a `guard` block) and it doesn't work. It seems like there's some time while `arView.session.configuration` is `nil`.

Comment: @Boris, what's your iPhone model?

Comment: @AndyFedoroff 11-inch iPad Pro, 3rd generation. Bought it last month.

Comment: @Boris, Updated my answer. I've checked it, it works.

Comment: @AndyFedoroff do you mind explaining why `touchesBegan` is needed? I don't want to wait for the user input to enable oclussion. I just want to have it enabled as soon as it's possible.

Comment: It's just for toggling Occlusion on and off when needed, because Occlusion is extremely CPU/GPU intensive.

Comment: @AndyFedoroff but why can't I (or how can I) start the app with people occlusion  enabled? If I try to access the `.configuration` while creating the view, it seems to be `nil`

Comment: There are several cases when you may get `nil`. Let your AR app to collect some data about scene before enabling occlusion. Use `.asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)`method  to schedule an execution at the specified time (for instance `deadline = .now() + 1.0`).

Comment: Take into consideration, you start getting depth data from Depth API only after starting a session + some time for camera tracking procedure + sync uploading your model. Depth data starts generating not from the first frame of ARSession, because occlusion comes from a second stage of ARKit – Scene Understanding...

Comment: Hope it helps, Boris!

Comment: @AndyFedoroff thank for the help. Is there a way of detecting when it's available instead of just hard coding waiting N seconds? Or will I have to poll?

Comment: Try something like this – `let frame = arView.session.currentFrame` and then `guard frame?.estimatedDepthData != nil else { print("depth is being captured") return }` inside delegate method `renderer(...)` or `session(...)`.